# How to add gif as preloader in wordpress?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a gif as preloader in wordpress. I want this gif to show exactly 5 seconds. I have found ways to do that in html/css/js but could not find how to do that in WordPress. I have found several plugin related to this but none of it really meets my requirement. Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: You want your site to take *5 seconds* to load? Why on earth would you want that?

Comment: Its one of the requirements of the client! :( Can you help?

Comment: Fulfilling this request would be doing them a disservice. 40% of visitors will leave a website if it doesn't load in ***2*** seconds, allegedly. Are you sure you're not misinterpreting them?

Comment: Yes. They gave a gif and asked to show its full length. Well, length can be reduced. But can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

add your code with class for ex .loading-wrapper in your header then add this code in your script

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('.loading-wrapper').slideUp();}, 5000);
```